# Why does update_post_meta change the value of my meta key?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, easy-digital-downloads

When I use the [update_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) function to change a value of a key:

- when it's a normal string it works
- but when the string is the same as a JSON file it appends some extra string.

For example, when I save this string:

```
a:1:{i:1;a:6:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:13:"attachment_id";s:1:"0";s:14:"thumbnail_size";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:3:"aaa";s:4:"file";s:3:"aaa";s:9:"condition";s:3:"all";}}
```

It is saved on the *wp_postmeta* table as:

```
s:162;"a:1:{i:1;a:6:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:13:"attachment_id";s:1:"0";s:14:"thumbnail_size";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:3:"aaa";s:4:"file";s:3:"aaa";s:9:"condition";s:3:"all";}}"
```

When I use a short string there are no problems. How can solve this?

My code:

```
$edd_files='a:1:{i:1;a:6:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:13:"attachment_id";s:1:"0";s:14:"thumbnail_size";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:3:"aaa";s:4:"file";s:3:"aaa";s:9:"condition";s:3:"all";}}';

update_post_meta($download_id,'edd_download_files',$edd_files);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because `update_post_meta()` serializes the value you pass as third parameter (see [update_metadata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_metadata/)).

Your `$edd_files` variable is a [serialized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array -not a "JSON file"- and `update_post_meta()` is serializing it *again* before saving it to the database, hence the reason why your serialized string changed like that.

I don't know why you're assigning `$edd_files` a serialized string but you can convert it back to an array using the [maybe_unserialize()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) function before saving it as a post meta and then the value will be saved on the database as a serialized string as expected:

```php
$edd_files = 'a:1:{i:1;a:6:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:13:"attachment_id";s:1:"0";s:14:"thumbnail_size";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:3:"aaa";s:4:"file";s:3:"aaa";s:9:"condition";s:3:"all";}}';

// Convert serialized string back into an array
$edd_files = maybe_unserialize($edd_files);

update_post_meta($download_id, 'edd_download_files', $edd_files);
```

Result:

[image: Serialized string on wp_postmeta]

Comment: Thanks your answer is very good. my problem was solved.